# Wix storing a path in a property

Tags: wix

I've been struggling with this Wix installer stuff..What I need to do is to store the JRE path selected by the person doing the installation in a property (I think that I need to do it like this). After having the property, I intend to use it somehow at the end of the installation, to write the value in a file..

Problem is that I can't seem to store the value of the DirectoryCombo/DirectoryList/PathEdit in the property...

My code is like this:

```
<!-- I use this to initialize the JREPATH to the most likely path..This works as expected -->
<CustomAction Id='INIT_JREPATH' Property='JREPATH' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]\Java' Execute='firstSequence' />


<!-- When this button is clicked, a new dialog is opened, where the UI elements have the path initialized above..This works as expected.. -->
<Control Id='BrowseButton' Type='PushButton' X='276' Y='126' Width='90' Height='18' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}B&amp;rowse...' TabSkip='no'>
   <Publish Property='SelectJreFolderDialog_Property' Value='JREPATH'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
   <Publish Event='SpawnDialog' Value='SelectJreFolderDialog'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>

<!-- This is where I got stuck -->
<Dialog Id='SelectJreFolderDialog' X='50' Y='50' Width='313' Height='223' Title='Browse for JRE Installation Folder' NoMinimize='yes'>
  <Control Id='OKButton' Type='PushButton' X='168' Y='198' Width='66' Height='18' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}OK' TabSkip='no' Default='yes'>
  **<!-- The code from below are various attempts that I tried to set the property at button click**
    <Publish Property='SelectJreFolder_Property' Value='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
    <Publish Event='SetProperty' Value='[SelectJreFolderDialog_Property]'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
  <!-- <Publish Event='SetTargetPath' Value='[SelectJreFolderDialog_Property]'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>  --> 

    <Publish Event='EndDialog' Value='Return'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>
<Control Id='CancelButton' Type='PushButton' X='240' Y='198' Width='66' Height='18' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Cancel' TabSkip='no' Cancel='yes'>
  <Publish Event='Reset' Value='{}'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
  <Publish Event='EndDialog' Value='Return'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>
<Control Id='BrowseText' Type='Text' X='6' Y='9' Width='60' Height='12' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;Browse:' TabSkip='no' />
<Control Id='FolderCombo' Type='DirectoryCombo' X='66' Y='6' Width='198' Height='120' Property='SelectJreFolderDialog_Property' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}MsiDirectoryCombo' TabSkip='no' Indirect='yes' Removable='yes' Fixed='yes' Remote='yes' RAMDisk='yes' Floppy='yes'>
 <Publish Property='SelectJreFolder_Property' Value= '[SelectJreFolderDialog_Property]' ><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>


 <!-- I have other elements here, a DirectoryList and a PathEdit, basically different approaches to selec the needed path..I did not add them because I don't think that they are relevant -->
</Dialog>
```

Problem is that..this is not working...when I try to set the value, what actually happens on the next dialog is that I get the value "JREPATH" instead of what the person doing the install selects...ex instead of C:\blsa bla\java

How can I fix this ? Any suggestions ?...The best approach if possible would be to store the value from the DirectoryCombo when Ok is pressed...not sure how doable is that..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by deleting the line:

```
<Publish Property='SelectJreFolder_Property' Value= '[SelectJreFolderDialog_Property]' ><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Publish Property='SelectJreFolderDialog_Property' Value='JREPATH'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
```

You need to set Value to [JREPATH], like this:

```
<Publish Property='SelectJreFolderDialog_Property' Value='[JREPATH]'><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
```